Calculation 4 week periods from ISO_week
So I have imported rows from a .csv file to Excel with Power Query. Now I want to transform my data as follows: add a column which calculates the number of the 4 week periode of the year from an existing column ISO_Week. So Iso_week 1-4 are period 1, Iso week 5 - 8 are Periode 2. And the one exception: Iso_week 53 also needs to be period 53.
The Excel formula would be: if(ISO_Week=53;13;roundup(ISO_Week/4;0))
What should I add in the Query editor to add a column as such?
Untill now I added a calculated column which divided ISO_Week by 4. So almost there. Only problem is now ISO_Week 53 will result in ISO_Week 14 and this shoudl be ISO_week 13.

Just use an If statement: if isoweeknum = 53 then "Period 13" else your_existing_formula
